# run dependency jobs if condtion is true in gitlab pipeline

Tags: github, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I want  to run dependency job if condition is true. Do we have that feasibility in git lab.When i manual triggered test job with DEPLOY variable then dependencies should run otherwise skip dependencies. I don't want to keep condition at build stage.

```
build:
 stage: build
 when: manual
 script:
   - echo build
test:
  stage: test
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - build
    if [ $deploy = 'true' ]
  script: 
   - echo test
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Gitlab documentation is a good starting point, especially the [rules section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

> The rules keyword can be used to include or exclude jobs in pipelines.
>
> Rules are evaluated in order until the first match. When matched, the
> job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the
> configuration. If included, the job also has certain attributes added
> to it.

This means you can use rules for such logical involvement, in your case it would look like

```
build:
 stage: build
 when: manual
 script:
   - echo build
test:
  stage: test
  needs: ['build'] # dependency on previous build stage
  script: 
   - echo test
  rules:
   - if: '$deploy == "true"' # when true, than run automatically
   - if: '$deploy != "true"' # when not true, than run only manually
     when: manual
```

I am not sure about the second rule, if it is needed or not. But i highly recommend to take a look at following directives in the GitLab documentation:

- [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)
- [needs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs)